# Create Countdown Timer Based On String

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on a script which would create a countdown timer based on string date and time that the admin defines. I have it already coded, however, there is a problem of users seeing different timers depending on their timezone. For instance, if the admin set the date and time to today, 4:50 PM (an hour from now), he'd see the timer at 01:00:00, while I'd see it at 04:00:00. Obviously, I'd like the timer to display the same for everyone.

Any ideas?

Here's part of the code:

```
//stringDate is the date and time string the admin sets
var splitSD = stringDate.split(' ');

    //isolate date, time, notation
    var splitDate = splitSD[0];
    var splitTime = splitSD[1];
    var splitNotation = splitSD[2];

    //isolate month, day, year
    var formatDate = splitDate.split('/');
    formatDate['month'] = formatDate[0];
    formatDate['day'] = formatDate[1];
    formatDate['year'] = formatDate[2];

    //isolate hour, minute, second
    var formatTime = splitTime.split(':');
    formatTime['hour'] = formatTime[0];
    formatTime['minute'] = formatTime[1];
    formatTime['second'] = '00';

    //change hour to 24-hour clock based on notation
    if(splitNotation == 'PM' && parseInt(formatTime['hour'])<12){
        formatTime['hour'] = parseInt(formatTime['hour']) + 12;
    }
    if(splitNotation == 'AM' && parseInt(formatTime['hour'])==12){
        formatTime['hour'] = parseInt(formatTime['hour']) - 12;
    }

    //prepend 0 in case...
    formatDate['month'] = (formatDate['month'].length == 1) ? '0'+formatDate['month'] : formatDate['month'];
    formatDate['day'] = (formatDate['day'].length == 1) ? '0'+formatDate['day'] : formatDate['day'];

    formatTime['hour'] = (formatTime['hour'].length == 1) ? '0'+formatTime['hour'] : formatTime['hour'];
    formatTime['minute'] = (formatTime['minute'].length == 1) ? '0'+formatTime['minute'] : formatTime['minute'];

    //format full date and prevent conversion to local time
    var fullFD = new Date(formatDate['year'] + '-' + formatDate['month'] + '-' + formatDate['day'] + 'T' + formatTime['hour'] + ':' + formatTime['minute'] + ':00-08:00');
    //make timestamp
    var fullFDTimestamp = Math.round(fullFD / 1000);

    return fullFDTimestamp;
```

Comment: i think you should use the servers time as reference

Comment: Use `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()`. This gives the difference, in minutes, between local time and GMT

Comment: @tewathia I used the getTimezoneOffset() like you suggested, and the timer works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer-ing my comment, as requested.*

Use Date.prototype's [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) method. It gives the difference, in minutes, between the local time and <del>GMT</del> UTC. You can calibrate the countdown timer to take into account this offset value and show the desired time.